# VLC: how to convert asf and stream it over http

Tags: ubuntu, stream, vlc, asf

I have a .asf videostream that I would need to stream over http. I need to convert it first as asf is not supported by iOS client.
I giving a try to ubuntu server + vlc but I do not manage to have it working:

When I issue:

```
vlc 'http://my_asf_stream.asf' --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=asf,dst=localhost:8083}'
```

(not 100% this is the correct command though...)

I have the following output:

```
VLC media player 2.0.4 Twoflower (revision 2.0.3+git20120830+r358)
[0x11bbd28] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0x11bbd28] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x7f65b4001108] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x118c108] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x118c108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x11ba7c8] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
[0x11ba7c8] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0x11cff18] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:
standard{access=http,mux=asf,dst=localhost:8083}'
[0x12647f8] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
[0x11ba7c8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.0.4 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

I cannot figure out where the problem is. I do not have X server on ubuntu as I use server edition but I guess this would not be require to decode/stream.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

It seems this command works better:

```
cvlc -vvv 'http://my_asf_stream.asf' --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100}:standard{access=http,mux=asf,dst=:8083}'
```

but I cannot see the streaming on my web browser at server:8083, neither in the iOS client.